# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ - Retrofit 2 Android

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I have received this retrofit 2

> ERROR:  java.lang.illegalstateexception: expected begin_array but was
>   begin_object

I don't know how to fix this

I have included my full code here

but My error is

> E/ddd: onFailure: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected
>   BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

What was wrong?

this is my JSON

```
 {"fom_combine":[{"mTitle":"Talaash","mYear":"2012"},{"mTitle":"Race 2","mYear":"2013"},{"mTitle":"October","mYear":"2018"},{"mTitle":"MS Dhoni: The Untold Story","mYear":"2016"},{"mTitle":"Phantom","mYear":"2015"},{"mTitle":"Baby","mYear":"2015"}]}
```

Search_Movie.class

```
public class Search_Movie {
@SerializedName("mTitle")
@Expose
private String mTitle;

@SerializedName("mYear")
@Expose
private long mYear;

public Search_Movie(String mTitle, long mYear) {
    this.mTitle = mTitle;
    this.mYear = mYear;
}

public String getmTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

public long getmYear() {
    return mYear;
}}
```

ApiClient.java

```
public class ApiClient {
public static final String BASE_URL = "https://example.com/search/";
public static Retrofit retrofit;

public static Retrofit getApiClient(){
    if (retrofit==null){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}}
```

ApiInterface

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@GET("fom_combine.php")
Call<List<Search_Movie>> getContact(
        @Query("name") String keyword
);}
```

Search_Activity.java

```
....
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private List<Search_Movie> contacts;
private Search_Adapter adapter;
private ApiInterface apiInterface;
ProgressBar progressBar;

    ....

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.prograss);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    fetchContact( "");

   .....
       public void fetchContact( String key){

    apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<List<Search_Movie>> call = apiInterface.getContact(key);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Search_Movie>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Search_Movie>> call, Response<List<Search_Movie>> response) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            contacts = response.body();
            adapter = new Search_Adapter(contacts, Search_Activity.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Search_Movie>> call, Throwable t) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(Search_Activity.this, "Error\n"+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your server is returning json object, but you're saying that you want json array. That is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create another class

```
public class FomCombine {
    @SerializedName("fom_combine")
    @Expose
    private List<Search_Movie> fom_combine;



    public FomCombine(List<Search_Movie> fom_combine) {this.fom_combine = fom_combine;}

public List<Search_Movie> getfom_combine() {
    return fom_combine;
}

 }
```

then change 
`Call<List<Search_Movie>> call = apiInterface.getContact(key);`  to

```
Call<FomCombine> call = apiInterface.getContact(key);
```

And the same with

```
@GET("fom_combine.php")
Call<List<Search_Movie>> getContact(
        @Query("name") String keyword
);}
```

To

```
@GET("fom_combine.php")
    Call<FomCombine> getContact(
            @Query("name") String keyword
    );}
```

And then

```
Call<FomCombine> call = apiInterface.getContact(key);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<FomCombine>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<FomCombine> call, Response<FomCombine> response) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                contacts = response.body().getfom_combine();
                adapter = new Search_Adapter(contacts, Search_Activity.this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<FomCombine> call, Throwable t) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(Search_Activity.this, "Error\n"+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Tried by still not working,   contacts = response.body(); this one expect list

Comment: How do i check if movie not found and show Toast Message. Where should i put this condition

Comment: @RohitKumarSehrawat for example you can check `if (contacts.isEmpty()){//show toast}`

Comment: java.util.List com.movies.FomCombine.getfom_combine()' on a null object reference. contacts = response.body().getfom_combine();
                if(contacts.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(Search_Activity.this,"Movie not found!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else{
                    adapter = new Search_Adapter(contacts, Search_Activity.this);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191167/discussion-between-rohit-kumar-sehrawat-and-yuri-popiv).

Answer (score 1):

The json you provide is an object not an array. 
You could provide juste the part with []

```
[
    {"mTitle":"Talaash","mYear":"2012"},
    {"mTitle":"Race 2","mYear":"2013"},
    {"mTitle":"October","mYear":"2018"},
    {"mTitle":"MS Dhoni: The Untold Story","mYear":"2016"},
    {"mTitle":"Phantom","mYear":"2015"},
    {"mTitle":"Baby","mYear":"2015"}
]
```

so not with the `{fom_combine :` part

Comment: You changed the json on the server ? if you can't change directly on the server and you have to work with the json object, try Yuri Popiv 's answer